# Holomorphic semigroups on $L^1$ spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, semigroups-of-operators

Let $E$ be a locally compact metric space and $\mu$ a non-negative Radon measure on $E$ (we also assume that the support is $E$).

I am concerned with holomorphic semigroups on $L^1(E,\mu)$. In particular, I assume the situation  where the semigroup is determined by a symmetric Markov process on $E$. So, the semigroup is an extension of a holomorphic (contraction) semigroup on $L^2(E,\mu)$.

I know that holomorphic (contraction) semigroups on $L^2(E,\mu)$ are extended to holomorphic semigroups on $L^p(E,\mu)$ with $1<p<\infty$. However, under what conditions would the semigroups be extended to holomorphic semigroups on $L^1(E,\mu)$.

I would appreciate if you could tell me the well-known conditions (even if there are strong restrictions).

I don't have a clear basis, but I think it is correct in the situation where $0$-order resolvents of symmetric Markov processes are bounded linear operators on $L^\infty(E,\mu)$.

Comment: One of the most prominent examples of a symmetric Markov semigroup that does not extend to a holomorphic semigroup on $L^1$ is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup on $L^2(\mathrm{Gaussian})$. The extension to $L^1$ is holomorphic if the measure is finite and the semigroup is ultracontractive, i.e., it maps $L^2$ to $L^\infty$. Both results can be found in Davies's book on heat kernels.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your comment. Is the OU semigroup a critical example? Is the semigroup generated by the SDE $dX=dB-X^3dt$ actually holomorphic on $L^1$ space? Here, $B$ denotes a one-dimensional Brownian motion, and we consider the $L^1$ space with respect to the invariant measure of the SDE. Anyway, I'll take a look at the Davies's book.

Comment: @sharpe I just noticed this old question of yours. Do you know if the semigroup generated by $D^2-x^3D$ is holomorphic in $L^1(e^{-x^4/4})$? I guess it is not...but I should think more about it.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer. However, I conjecture that the semigroup is holomorphic on $L^1(e^{-x^4/4})$. In fact, the $L^p$-spectrum of $D^2-x^3 D$ is independent of $p \in [1,\infty]$, isn't it?

Comment: In the meanwhile I had a look: it is not analytic in $L^1(e^{-x^4/4}\, dx)$ even though the spectrum is indipendent of $p$. Some of these questions are treated in a joint paper with E. Priola (some classes of non-analytic Markov semigroups). We proved thah the above semigroup is not analyic in spaces of continuous functions and then, since it is self-adjoint, the same holds in $L^1$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you for telling me that my conjecture is wrong. I'll take a look at the joint paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General reference:**
A very useful overview about extrapolation properties of semigroups on the $L^p$-scale is given in Chapter 7, and in particular Section 7.2, of the survey "[Wolfgang Arendt: Semigroups and Evolution Equations: Functional
Calculus, Regularity and Kernel Estimates](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1874-5717(04)80003-3)" (this survey is Chapter 1 of the "Handbook of Differential Equations: Evolutionary Equations (2002)").

**Specific results:**

- In the third paragraph on page 64 of the survey, it is mentioned that there exists an unbounded domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with rough boundary such that the semigroup generated by the Neumann Laplace operator is not analytic on $L^1(\Omega)$. This example is attributed to Kunstmann there (the reference given is "[Peer C. Kunstmann: $L_p$-spectral properties of the Neumann Laplacian on horns, comets and stars (Math. Z., 2002)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002090100313)"). I don't have access to this article right now, but it might be worthwhile to have a look at it since the aforementioned counterexample probably gives a good indication of what is *not* true.
- For open sets $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ an important concept for semigroups on $L^2(\Omega)$ are *Gaussian estimates*. They are discussed in Section 7.4 of the survey article by Arendt. For semigroups that satisfy Gaussian estimates, holomorphy extrapolates from $L^2(\Omega)$ to $L^1(\Omega)$; see Subsection 7.4.3 of the survey.

Unfortunately, I don't know any criteria on $L^2(E)$ for more general spaces $E$ (but, obviously, this does not imply that such criteria don't exist).

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful comments. It seems that holomorphy of semigroups associated with diffusion processes have been investigated in detail.